# How to set different start page for each user group?

Tags: 2010, permissions, publishing-site, publishing-page

I have two different user groups in my Sharepoint 2010 site and start page is default.aspx. I want to show nothing or another page for only one user group as start page. How can I solve this? Is it possible in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: default.aspx is homepage for your sitecollection ?

Comment: @yaron yes it is homepage.

Comment: and this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769027/sharepoint-redirecting-users-or-groups-from-a-page-to-another

Comment: Duplicate question of [force-a-sharepoint-groups-landing-page][1]


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24467/force-a-sharepoint-groups-landing-page

Answer (score 3):

I think that the simplest way is to use custom web part. This web part should be added to the default.aspx and checks users. If the user belongs to the needed group the web part redirects this user to a different page.

Comment: is it possible to handle it in Default.aspx?

Comment: Why not? See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034943/webpart-that-redirect-if-user-is-not-in-a-specific-sharepoint-security-group). It includes code that you need.

Comment: this link might help as well 

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/redirect-a-sharepoint-site-by-using-the-content-editor-web-part.aspx

Comment: Please share the web part code for redirect to different page.
Thank you.